# Git pull error: RPC failed; curl 16 Error in the HTTP2 framing layer. fatal: expected flush after ref listing

Tags: git, gitlab

Forgive my ignorance of GitLab but I keep getting this error after thinking I resolved it. I'm unsure how I'm having such difficulties finding what it even means, maybe I've used all my allotted brain cells and there are none left.

```
$ git pull 'https://gitlab....'
error: RPC failed; curl 16 Error in the HTTP2 framing layer
fatal: expected flush after ref listing
```

Background/things I've tried:

I used Git as version control from two different computers. I only have one branch. The only thing in the .git/refs/heads/ is 'master'. I think it started as a merge conflict but I thought I resolved it. I also thought it might be a file that's too large? or maybe it's because I'm using master on two computers? But it worked before with this technique.

I tried just cloning the entire directory again in a separate spot but same error. I can push/pull it fine from my other computer.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Pick just one of GitHub or GitLab, because they are different systems. (However, your issue is probably caused by a middleware box messing with your https data-stream. If you can use ssh instead of https, that is likely to bypass the problem. Alternatively, make sure you're not using some broken antivirus software.) I edited out the github tag based on the `gitlab....` part of the question above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to force git to use HTTP 1.1 by setting git config like this

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
```

then pull

if you want to set it back to HTTP2 you can do the same

```
git config --global http.version HTTP/2
```

Comment: Funny story, this morning I go to try it and it works fine. But I changed my http- version anyways so fingers crossed this makes it not happen again. Thanks.