Private repo cloning gives git error, although I am a collaborator
I am trying to clone a git repo which is private and I am a collaborator of.
I am copy-pasting the url directly from GitHub so this is not a typo issue. And also this issue appears only when trying to clone this one specific repo.
I run:
gin clone <url from github to the repo>
and I get:
fatal: read error: Invalid argument fatal: expected flush after ref listing
I am using git bash in VSCode. Any ideas as to what can be done so I can clone this repo without issues?
I have my git user and email setup and I don't know what else to do. I have read around in SO but I do not meet the same issue being reported.
I have an access token. I have tried to run:
git clone --verbose <url to repo>
and nothing changes.

Maybe you should run git clone and not gin clone?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72987674/git-pull-error-rpc-failed-curl-16-error-in-the-http2-framing-layer-fatal-exp

@mkrieger1 Nope, sorry, does not help. And yeah, typo. But this was not the case in my git bash terminal.
